# Automatically renaming Schematic or Page in OrCAD

Tags: orcad

#### Background:

I would like to start using a version control system (Git) with OrCAD in my organization, and even though it seems that it's not going to be as beneficial as using Git with text-based files, I still think it is going to be a huge improvement over the current email-based flow.

However, one of the concerns that was brought up by my colleague is something that I can't ignore.

#### Here is the concern:

Since diff-ing is not possible due to the binary nature of DSN files, all the comparison would be done manually by opening two or more versions of the same schematic, and then jumping from tab to tab. This is not a problem yet, because this is how we compare the files now. The problem is that these two tabs would both have the same title on them, in form of SCHEMATIC1:PAGE1.

Comparing work between two such tabs is now prone to confusion (is this a newer version of the schematic? Is it an older one?), because the title block is not always in view.

#### Possible solutions:

1. Renaming a schematic or a page manually before each commit

- I like this option the least. Not only it introduces one more action item for engineers, it also is prone to human error.

2. Automatically renaming a schematic or a page using git tools (git hooks to be precise) after each commit by *editing DSN files directly*

- This options should be easy to implement, but honestly, it's a bit scary to perform manipulations directly on the DSN file. If OrCAD updates their format, or even if I misunderstand their format, this potentially could result in inability to open files. I was thinking of making these names a fixed-length strings with a defined format, and then replacing them with new ones, but what if in the next version of OrCAD, say a CRC will added to DSN file? Bottom line: this would be essentially relying on an undocumented feature, hence not an ideal way.

#### Other things I though of

I tried editing .opj files, to append a fake folder that would have an auto-generated name. The folder would then be displayed in the Project Manager pane on the left. The folder itself works and looks fine, but it turned out that switching tabs does not switch projects in the Project Manager pane on the left (i.e. when you switch tabs, the PM pane stays unchanged), so this method is essentially useless.

I am not a hardware engineer; my background is in software, so my view is quite limited.

What could be an acceptable approach to provide an engineer with the schematic revision info without constantly having them to look at title blocks? I would prefer something that could be some automatically, but in absence of such solutions manual processes are also ok.

Comment: Does OrCAD provide a way to export its data files in a text format? (Ideally a lossless export, but maybe netlist + bom would be sufficient?) Maybe you could use that in a hook script, and keep the exported DSN-text under source control. Think it might depend on how much information is lost when you export-then-import the data.

Comment: @MarkU A very interesting interesting idea, thank you! I will have to research this topic a bit more, but yes, OrCAD can export its schematics as XML files. Even if it does not fly in the end - for example because there are other references that get lost in the process of export/import, or because it's not convenient - this still may be super-useful for something else, like as an example `git blame` would become a possibility